# How to get templates instantiation statistics in clang on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, clang, clang++

I'm exploring different aspects of templates in C++ and want to dive into this topic a bit more.

For instance, I have a very simple function template in some header file:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T value)
{
    (void)value;
}
```

And I want to get statistics how much time it has been instantiation during building some code.
Ok, maybe getting this kind of statistics will be complicated. The overal amount of templates instantiations (10 times, 20 times and etc) during building some code will be enough for now.

For example I have the follings files: `a.h` `a.cpp` `b.h` `b.cpp` `c.h` `c.cpp` `main.cpp` and `CMakeLists.txt`.
I completed the build process and want to get statistics.

I have tried to analyze the output of executing clang build with `-ftime-report` option, but it's not what I want to get. It's more about execution time and percentages of different parts of compilation and it's related to concrete translation unit.

Is it possible to get these statistics?

Comment: @CurDev Maybe you could fill a container with the every (uniquely) encountered `typeid(T)` and then count the occurrences.

Comment: OP, do you want to count the number of unique template arguments the template is used with? Or do you also want to include duplicate instantiations by different translation units?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That comment still do not tell how to measure the time it has been instantiation during building some code. Though it might be possible to answer OP's question without any external tool.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I want to include duplicate instantiations by different translation units in this counting.

Comment: Even though I think it is valid question and I hope someone will answer, you could also ask the very same question on LLVM's Github, tagged as question: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+clang+label%3Aquestion

Comment: Btw, I suspect it should be trivial to do with Clang Plugins, https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangPlugins.html, I could try to come up with one in some free time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If just the number of instantiations is enough (not the time spent on them), this should work:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

inline int &GetCounter()
{
    static int ret = 0;
    return ret;
}

template <typename T>
static const auto register_type = []{
    GetCounter()++;
    return nullptr;
}();

template <typename T>
void foo(T value)
{
    (void)value;

    // Instantiate `register_type<T>`.
    (void)std::integral_constant<const std::nullptr_t *, &register_type<T>>{};
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << GetCounter() << '\n'; // 3

    if (false)
    {
        foo(1);
        foo(1.2);
        foo(1.2);
        foo(1.2f);
        foo(1.2f);
    }
}
```

Note `static` on the `register_type` variable, which allows us to count duplicate instantiations done by different TUs.

I believe this also means that `foo()` technically violates the one definition rule (since in each TU it uses a different `register_type` variable), but this shouldn't cause any issues in practice, since when the linker deduplicates those instantiations, it doesn't matter which one gets picked, as all of them compile to the same assembly anyway.

---

If you do need the time spent on instantiations, I believe Clang's `-ftime-trace` is your best option. I'd run it for every TU, then combine the results somehow.